# Attempt to use a deleted function with C++11 threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14

I am trying to create a ThreadPool class which has a constructor like this

```cpp
    ThreadPool(size_t numberOfThreads)
    : workerThreads(numberOfThreads) {
      workerThreads.reserve(numberOfThreads);
      for(int i =0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
        workerThreads.emplace_back(std::thread(&ThreadPool::doJob, this));
      }
    }
```

This fails to compile for me and throws following error

```
error: attempt to use a deleted function
    __invoke(_VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<1>(__t)), _VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<_Indices>(__t))...);
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/thread:352:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::__thread_execute<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void
      (ThreadPool::*)(std::__1::function<void (char *, std::__1::list<std::__1::basic_string<char>,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > > *)>), ThreadPool *, 2>' requested here
    __thread_execute(*__p, _Index());
```

As per other answers to similar question I also tried doing this

```cpp
        workerThreads.emplace_back(std::thread(&ThreadPool::doJob, std::ref(*this)));
```

This is reproducing same issue as well. I am compiling my code with `clang` `c++14` on macos

Here is complete program where this reproduces

```cpp
class ThreadPool {
  public:
    ThreadPool(size_t numberOfThreads)
    : workerThreads(numberOfThreads) {
      for(int i =0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
        workerThreads[i] = std::make_shared<std::thread>(std::thread(&ThreadPool::doJob, this));
      }
    }

    ThreadPool(const ThreadPool& tp) {
      workerThreads = tp.workerThreads;
      jobQueue = tp.jobQueue;
    }

    std::function<void(char*, std::list<std::string>*)> getNextJob() {
      if(!jobQueue.empty()) {
        std::function<void(char*, std::list<std::string>*)> job = jobQueue.front();
        jobQueue.pop_front();
        return job;
      } 

      throw std::runtime_error("No jobs to process, thread finished");
    }

    void addWork(std::function<void(char*, std::list<std::string>*)> job) {
      lockListMutex.lock();
      jobQueue.push_back(job);
      lockListMutex.unlock();
    }

  private:
    // performs actual work
    void doJob(std::function<void(char*, std::list<std::string>*)> job) {
      try {
        lockListMutex.lock();
        getNextJob();
        lockListMutex.unlock();
      } catch (std::runtime_error &e) {

      }
    }

    // a vector containing worker threads
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::thread>> workerThreads;

    // a queue for jobs
    std::list<std::function<void(char*, std::list<std::string>*)>> jobQueue;

    // a mutex for synchronized insertion and deletion from list
    std::mutex lockListMutex;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int numThreads = 1;
    ThreadPool* pool = new ThreadPool(numThreads);
}
```

Comment: what kind of container are you using? If it is a vector, it is assumed the underlying type (which happens to be std::thread), needs to be copy-constructable, which is just happens to be not allowed to be copied.

Comment: yes its a `std::vector`

Comment: You may use a vector of pointers, since std::thread pointers are allowed to be copied. But it will be up to you to join or detach all the threads on vector destruction.

Comment: btw, in you constructor you are creating `numberOfThreads * 2` of threads. Moreover, your "reserve" makes no sence, since you have already instantiated a vector of the same size. It will not allocate any more memory for you. And emplacing back will add twice as much elements to your vector. Assuming you use a copy-constructable class, you need to use ```ThreadPool(size_t size) : workerThreads(size, std::thread(&ThreadPool::doJob, this)) {}```

Comment: I tried using `shared_ptr` like this `workerThreads[i] = std::make_shared<std::thread>(std::thread(&ThreadPool::doJob, this));` but still getting same issue

Comment: I use `std::vector<std::thread>` routinely on macOS rig, and have for years. The only bizarre thing I see *besides* the amount of time this has gone without a [mcve] is the `workerThreads(size)` in your member initialization list, which is clearly wrong. No will `workerThreads(size, std::thread(&ThreadPool::doJob, this))`, which would require `std::thread` be copyable, and we already know it isn't (nor is it copy-assignable). It *should*, however, be move-able.

Comment: `doJob` has a parameter of type `std::function<void(char*, std::list<std::string>*)>`. Therefore, when invoked, you need to provide a corresponding _argument_. This argument is completely missing in your `thread` constructor, where you pass only `this`. Don't you actually want to pass elements of `jobQueue` here?

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica yes

Comment: @WhozCraig I have added minimal reproducible example

Comment: I concur with Daniel. That won't work because your thread proc `doJob` doesn't take an empty argument list. If you used a generic thread proc with no args (and put the onus on arguments during the *push*), it would probably do what you want.

Comment: @WhozCraig indeed that was the issue, thanks!

Comment: Do you really need your `ThreadPool` to be copyable? Doesn't make much sense. Without this requirement, you could use simply a _vector of threads_ instead of a _vector of shared pointers of threads_.

Comment: No I don't need it, I was just experimenting with it. I will remove that, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `doJob` member function has a parameter `job` of type `std::function<void(char*, std::list<std::string>*)>`, you need to provide a corresponding argument when this function is called. Therefore, calling of this function in a new thread this way is invalid:

```
std::thread(&ThreadPool::doJob, this)  // no argument for job passed
```

You either need to provide an argument, or, since the jobs should be likely dequeued from `jobQueue`, remove the `job` parameter from `doJob`:

```
void doJob()
{
   ... // dequeue job from jobQueue and execute it
```

Comment: Indeed. `proc()` is what my work queue thread procs look like . My queue is usuall a `std::queue<std::function<void()>>`, and I template out a push member taking variadic args to craft a call object via an oldie but goodie, `std::bind` again the forwarded `fn` callable and fowarded variadic arguments, if any. that's what goes in the queue, and eventually pulled and fired in the thread pool. nice catch noticing the `doJob` args. props.